# python rdkit signaturizer code taking too much time to process

Tags: python, rdkit

I am new to python and using python 3.11 to execute a code I got instruction of. I am basically running a command using rdkit and signaturizer, but the last line starting with "sign = " has been taking more than 30 minutes to process. I was wondering whether this is normal and how I could fix this.

```
import sys 
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/')
try:
    from rdkit import Chem
    from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
except ImportError:
    print('Stopping RUNTIME. Colaboratory will restart automatically. Please run again.') 
    exit()
import signaturizer
from signaturizer import Signaturizer
sign = Signaturizer(['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','C1','C2','C3','C4','C5','D1','D2','D3','D4','D5','E1','E2','E3','E4','E5'])
```

Thank you!

I am trying to wait if there is any other thing I can do.

Comment: "Generating 1000 signatures for one bioactivity spaces takes less than 4 seconds on an average machine with 4 cores." That's what they state as a benchmark [here](https://pypi.org/project/signaturizer/). If you want to improve the speed you need to modify the [`Serializer`code](https://gitlabsbnb.irbbarcelona.org/packages/signaturizer/-/blob/master/signaturizer/signaturizer.py) itself. Maybe you can ask the maintainer or ask someone experienced with tensorflow and alike. I feel like changing displayed code snippet won't help much.